# Adding Push-To-Talk (PTT) / Mute to 3-pin XLR Cable

Tags: audio, wiring, cables

Is it possible to add PTT/Mute to a 3-pin standard terminating XLR cable (with +48V phantom power)?

In my case, I have found myself with a Astatic 40-119 microphone base with a PTT switch that "only" provides dry contact between the 4 & 5 pin of the 5-pin XLR cable. Can I use this fact to cut the power to the condenser mic, or is there some better circuity to accomplish the mute? The base works great otherwise. (There is a competing model that mutes the microphone on a standard 3-pin XLR cable that I've included the spec sheet for completeness.)

- [40-119 MIC BASE Spec Sheet](https://www.cadaudio.com/images/uploads/40-119.data.pdf)

  > This unit features a dependable momentary push
  > switch that provides a dry contact between pins 4 and 5 of the cable terminating
  > XLR connector. The switch can be configured for either "push-to-open" or "push-to-close" using the slide switch located on the underside of the base. The 40-119
  > base is used to control an independent device while audio signal from the mic is
  > always on.

  Just to note: the mic does work as described. Maybe the mentioned "independent device" can mute the mic :)
- [40-116 MIC BASE Spec Sheet](https://www.cadaudio.com/images/uploads/40-116.data.pdf) (don't have this, for comparison)

  > The circuit contains a highly reliable switch to operate
  > a 55dB mute which will effectively kill audio output without causing a potentially
  > damaging phantom power "thump" when used with electret type microphones.

These questions were helpful to me but the first two are microcontroller focused. The latter 3.5mm also has a power component, I'm researching into it more.

1. [Microphone mute anti-pop circuit works but still picks up a little audio](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/272290/microphone-mute-anti-pop-circuit-works-but-still-picks-up-a-little-audio)
2. [5v Electret microphone to PC mute switch pop help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/141499/5v-electret-microphone-to-pc-mute-switch-pop-help)
3. [3.5mm Push to Talk Switch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/465044/3-5mm-push-to-talk-switch)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have read the 40-119 "datasheet" and didn't find it terribly useful. It might be that pins 1,2 and 3 of the 3-pin XLR go straight through to the 5-pin XLR and pins 4 and 5 of the XLR are attached to the switch. I'm not positive about this. If it is, then yes, a simple circuit with at most 1 capacitor and 1 or two resistors should be possible for push-to-talk. Hardware required is one 5-pin XLR connector to plug into the base, and one 3-pin XLR connector to connect to the cable taking the signal from that circuit to some external device/amplifier.

Comment: pin 1 carries the phantom power, pins 2 and 3 are the differential audio signal , grounding one of them will make a loud pop.

Comment: @Jasen, per wikipedia, a three pin XLR has pin 1 is ground, pin 2 is hot, and pin 3 is cold. My understanding is phantom power is connected to the hot pin (and the ground).

Comment: That's not how phantom power works on balanced microphones. everything you've learned about phone jack micorphones is inapplicable.

Comment: Are you saying that pin 1 is not ground?

Comment: It's ground, but it's only used to complete the phantom power circuit  the audio is on pins 2 and 3  and it not ground referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the switch mode to push to open and connect it across the signal lines. (pins 2 and 3)

releasing the PTT will mute the microphone signal by shunting it.

So, connect pin 4 to pin 2 and pin 5 to pin 3

With a 20 foot cable this may not work very well. if you are allowed to modify the base make the same connection internally instead.

Comment: Is shunting the microphone signal a good idea with phantom power applied?

Comment: It's common practice, microphones have high impedance so there no change of damage.

Comment: wouldn't that short out the phantom power?

Comment: no because  ground is the return for the pohantom power and it does not connect to ground.